# How to add and fetch the  Value From dynamically created textfiled with tag from Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to add and fetch the value from dynamically created textfield with tag from plist....
how could i do this?

```
Txt_New_Estimated = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(360, textPosY , 130, 65)];
Txt_New_Estimated.delegate = self;
Txt_New_Estimated.text=@"";
Txt_New_Estimated.tag = i; 
Txt_New_Estimated.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[Txt_New_Estimated addTarget:self action:@selector(C6Loop)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];//UIControlEventEditingDidEnd
Txt_New_Estimated.placeholder = @"Estimated";
Txt_New_Estimated.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:23];
Txt_New_Estimated.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
Txt_New_Estimated.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[scrollview addSubview:Txt_New_Estimated];
[textFieldArray addObject:Txt_New_Estimated];
```

how to add object with tag like this ...

[form1Array1 addObject:Txt_New_ONU.text];//3

i want to add the value every index of textfiled on tag ......

how to add , save n retrieve the value on textfild tag through plist.... like this line

[form1Array1 addObject:Txt_New_ONU.text];//3

it save the value on 3rd position on plist....  how to save  n retrieve the value dynamically created textfield on tag , i position n how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the content of a plist to an array:

```
// Path to the plist (in the application bundle)
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistFile" ofType:@"plist"];

// Build the array from the plist
NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Iterate through the array to create text fields with tags and add it to a new array:

```
NSMutableArray* newArr = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=0; i<[arr count]; i++)
{
    UITextField field = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame...
    field.tag = i;
    (...) // other initialization code
    [newArr addObject:field];
}
```

Comment: This is not working sir For me , Please Give some other idea...Please.

Comment: OK, what exactly is not working for you? Is there a compiler error? Is the tag not stored properly? You can't use this solution because of some reason?

Comment: Can you add logs to see what values are you storing and getting back? Or can you see the values when debugging?

Comment: Sir ,your code working fine now , i change something in my code and try your code again and its working fine now.... Thank You very much sir.... Gr888 Help....

Comment: Great! Could you please consider marking my response as the answer if it resolved your problem?

Comment: Yeah sure, I already click on ""Was this post useful to you""""